# Transfer of an instanced object into a class

Tags: php, object, transfer, global

I was wondering what is the best way to transfer an instanced object into another class for local usage. I am also curious if this makes a differences with regards to memory usage.

I figured, there are mainly two ways:

**1.) Transfer instanced objects via referencing to $GLOBALS:**

```
class UserLogHandler {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->DB = $GLOBALS['DB'];
    $this->Security = $GLOBALS['Security'];
  }
  public function doSomeWork() {
    $this->DB->someMethod;
  }
}
```

or
**2.) Transfer via handover:**

```
class UserLogHandler($DB,$Security) {
    public function doSomeWork() {
        $DB->someMethod;
    }
}
```

It seems to me, that option 2 might be better suited for a complicated environment, although I find option 1 more appealing. Anyhow I would prefer a technical and/or logical explanation why to use one option over the other. If there is another, better option please let me know as well.

Thanks in advance and best wishes,
Thomas

Comment: Option 2, every time. Read up on dependency injection if you want the details, but it'll dramatically improve your code on every level. If you're ever writing the word globals, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Dear iainn, Thanks. Will use proper injection instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a good question. I will say it depends upon your need. Lets analyze both your options one by one.

Before starting, keep in mind that your object should always a complete object. It should not have a incomplete state. You can refer to this article for more understanding https://matthiasnoback.nl/2018/07/objects-should-be-constructed-in-one-go/

**1.) Transfer instanced objects via referencing to $GLOBALS:**

You must never use such methods as they are confusing. $GLOBALS lacks to tell you where and how a particular variable was created so You can't never be sure if this variable exist or what it holds. I will suggest you to use dependency injection for it

```
use DB;
use Security;

class UserLogHandler
{
    public function __construct(DB $DB, Security $Security)
    {
        $this->DB = $DB;
        $this->Security = $Security;
    }

    public function doSomeWork()
    {
        $this->DB->someMethod;
    }

}
```

See how you can now be sure that from where $DB and $Security where injected and what they hold. You can even enforce type of variable using type indication like `Security $Security`.

This method comes handy when your class is heavy dependent on a particular variable. e.g. A model class will always need DB adapter or a PDF generator library will need PDF class essentially.

**2.) Transfer via handover**

This works as you expected but I think you made mistake while defining it. You need to write it like following.

```
class UserLogHandler
{
    public function doSomeWork($DB, $Security)
    {
        $DB->someMethod;
    }
}
```

This method comes handy when you need a particular variable in a particular function only. Example for it, will be like we need to get records from a model for some particular condition. So we can pass value in function and get results according to value.

```
use DB;
use Security;

class UserLogHandler
{
    public function __construct(DB $DB, $Security)
    {
        $this->DB = $DB;
        $this->Security = $Security;
    }

    public function doSomeWork($value)
    {
        if ($value = 'something') {
            $this->DB->someMethod;
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see that both methods can be used in conjugation. It only depends what is your requirement

Comment: Dear hanish, Thank you for your decent reply. Indeed there was an obvious error in the definition. Thanks for correction! I understand now that using GLOBALS seems like a bad idea in this context. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @barkeldiho, Glad to know that it helped you. Does it answers your question completely or I missed anything?